# This question regarding pega, I need to validate age property on client side,

Tags: pega

Age is a property created in work-custmerDetails, A case type. A text input
In the Validations Tab , edit validate.

I have created a edit validate rule from data model to check age between 18 to 65 only, In a form to capture details But it is a java code . I need to validate on client side only, is there any other way, already tried with validate rule from process category which is server side validation.

Comment: You can implement your custom javascript function with desired validation. Then in your Section, configure "Run Script" action triggered by Change event. Pass the .Age value as a parameter to your function.